# write results sequentially in a loop in r

Tags: r, loops, url-rewriting

I have a bunt of single files which need to apply a test. I need to find the way to write automatically results of each file into a file. Here is what I do:

```
library(ape)
stud_files <- list.files("path/dir/data",full.names = T)
for (f in stud_files)  {
df <- read.table(f, header=TRUE, sep=";")
df_xts <- as.xts(df$cola, order.by = as.Date(df$colb,"%m/%d/%Y"))
pet <- testa(df_xts)
res <- data.frame(estimate = pet$estimate,
                 p.value=pet$p.value,
                logi = pet$alternative)
write.dna(res,file = "res_testa.xls",format = "sequential")
}
```

This loop works well, except the last command which aim to write the results of each file consecutively, it saved only the last performance. And the results save as string, not a table as I define above (data.frame). Any idea in this case? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it an option to save the res for each iteration, bind them together afterwards and write them to a file in one go?

Comment: Try adding "append=TRUE" to your write statement

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam: my idea is to save it immediately before turning to next file. I think it should be simpler than the option of binding them in a table and write them all, or?

Comment: @Hari It depends, would you run out of memory if you kept all the results till the end?

Answer (score 2):

Check `help(write.dna)`.

> write.dna(x, file, format = "interleaved", append = FALSE,
>             nbcol = 6, colsep = " ", colw = 10, indent = NULL,
>             blocksep = 1)
>
> append a logical, if TRUE the data are appended to the file without
>   erasing the data possibly existing in the file, otherwise the file (if
>   it exists) is overwritten (FALSE the default).

Set `append = TRUE` and you should be all set.

As some of the comments point out, however, you are probably better off generating your table, and then writing it all at once to a file. Unless you have billions of files, you likely won't run out of memory.

Here is how I would approach this.

```
library(ape)
library(data.table)

stud_files <- list.files("path/dir/data",full.names = T)

sumfunc <- function(f) {

  df <- read.table(f, header=TRUE, sep=";")
  df_xts <- as.xts(df$cola, order.by = as.Date(df$colb,"%m/%d/%Y"))
  pet <- testa(df_xts)
  res <- data.table(estimate = pet$estimate,
                    p.value=pet$p.value,
                    logi = pet$alternative)
  return(res)

}

lres <- lapply(stud_files, sumfunc)
dat <- rbindlist(lres)

write.table(dat,
            file = "res_testa.csv",
            sep = ",",
            quote = FALSE,
            row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Many thanks. The results are listed, but in line like this:
4 1
estimate 2195
p.value  1.40119324
logi     true chang
Date     1960-05-03

I would expect that they appear in a table when I wrote data.frame, how could I keep them in a table/data.frame when I write it? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `write.dna`? You could use `write.csv` or `write.table` which would output your result `res` in tabular format. It has the same `append = TRUE` parameter.

Comment: I actually use write.dna for the first time which aim to write the results consecutively in a loop. I tried write.table and write.scv or write.xlsx, but it has the same problem.

Comment: Just edited the answer to include some code to generate the table first in R, and then write it to file. Hard to test without your data files, but this should work.

Comment: That's awesome! The code works perfectly. You saved almost my days. Truly thank you